# ¿Como buscar en dos campos de una colección en Mongo?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Estoy tratando de hacer una búsqueda en una colección de mongo, cuya estructura es la siguiente:

```
{
     nombre: "daniel",
     apellido: "Martinez"
}
```

Lo que quiero es buscar por nombre y apellido de manera conjunta, es decir: `daniel Martinez`. Actualmente la consulta la estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
  const queryUsers = {
    $or:[
      {name: {$regex: text_search}},
      {last_name: {$regex: text_search}}      
    ]
  }
```

Pero la consulta solo se hace en un solo campo, no en ambos. ¿Alguien me puede decir como debo hacer la consulta para que se haga en conjunto con `name` y `last_name`?

Comment: ¿Si el valor de name o last_name está vacío se debería ignorar el documento o tomarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas que todas las condiciones se cumplan, debes de cambiar el condicional `OR` por `AND`. Al usar AND la consulta selecciona los documentos de la colección que coincidan con todas las condiciones‎.

Para especificar condiciones AND en MongoDB utiliza una coma entre cada condición:

```
    // Ejemplo de consulta con AND en MongoDB
   db.users.find({name: 'daniel', last_name:'Martinez'})

   // En NodeJS podría quedar así
   User.find({name: 'daniel', last_name:'Martinez'});
```

Comment: La cuestión es que estoy buscando toda la cadena en conjunto, lo que estoy haciendo es lo siguiente:

`User.find({name: 'Daniel Martinez', last_name: 'Daniel Martinez'})`

la respuesta que me diste si funciona cuando ya se cual es el nombre y el apellido y los recibo por separado.

Comment: Es mejor implementar la lógica en el frontend o con NodeJS para separar nombre y apellido. Podrías utilizar el regex en el input para nombre y apellido, o bien un input para cada uno. Que sea el usuario quien decida cuál es cada entrada y no tratar que la BD adivine. Tu consulta no es muy buena que se diga, viendo el modelo que tienes.